# Draw a circle by pressing ctrl & dragging mouse in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to develop a function with leaflet which make user be able to draw a circle by pressing ctrl & dragging mouse, as the following

```
    let mouseDownPos = null
    let mouseUpPos = null

    L.Map.CircleSelector = L.Map.Drag.extend({
        _onMouseDown: function(e) {
            if (!e.ctrlKey)
                return

            let map = this._map
            map.dragging.disable()

            mouseDownPos = map.containerPointToLatLng(this._point)
        }, 
        _onMouseUp: function(e) {
            if (!e.ctrlKey) {
                this._map.dragging.enable()
                return
            }

            let map = this._map
            mouseUpPos = map.containerPointToLatLng(this._point)

            let radius = map.distance(mouseDownPos, mouseUpPos)
            L.circle(mouseDownPos, {radius: radius}).addTo(map)

            map.dragging.enable()
        }
    })

    L.Map.mergeOptions({circleSelector: true})
    L.Map.addInitHook('addHandler', 'circleSelector', L.Map.CircleSelector)
```

When I press ctrl & drag mouse on the map, it still does not work.

I've tried to print text to console at the beginning in _onMouseDown(), it shows nothing.

It seems that the event doesn't trigger.

What should I need to modify? Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/)? That plugin has a circle drawing option.  Maybe you could either use that or take a peek at their source code.

Comment: @user: I know the plugin. I'd like to develop this function by myself as a practice, but encounter this issue. Maybe I can trace the source code first, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I extend [leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) to approach my goal.

Refer to the source code of L.Draw.Circle, I extend my selector from L.Draw.Circle. The mainly modified part is in _onMouseUp, as the following

```
    L.Map.CircleSelector = L.Draw.SimpleShape.extend({
        _onMouseUp: function (e) {
            // TODO
            // 1. Get the circle center & radius
            // 2. Calculate distances between center & markers
            // 3. If the distance in step 2 <= radius, it is in the circle
            // 4. Anything you'd like to do......
        }
    })
```

The rest code of the event can be referred to L.Draw.Circle, e.g., addHooks, _onMouseMove......